# Function that stores one for ever number that is not zero in a vector

Tags: r

How can I write a function that changes any value not zero to 1?

My current approach:

```
> numbersGreaterZeroAreOne(c(0.001, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4))
[1] 1 0 1 1 1 1
```

and my implementation:

```
numbersGreaterZeroAreOne <- function(x) {
    x <- x/x
    x[is.na(x)] <- 0
    return(x)
}
```

However, I think my function works, but I don't quite like it, it seems unnatural to use devision through zero and `NaN` values.

Comment: z = c(0.001, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4); z[z>0] = 1 ?

Comment: `(!!c(0.001, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4))+0#[1] 1 0 1 1 1 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use vector assignment `[<-` and the logical operator `!=`

```
> x <- c(0.001, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
> f <- function(x) { x[x != 0] <- 1; x }
> f(x)
# [1] 1 0 1 1 1 1
```

Or you could do a little trickery

```
> g <- function(x) { as.logical(x)+0 }
> g(x)
# [1] 1 0 1 1 1 1
```

The latter seems to be quite a bit faster

```
> library(microbenchmark)
> microbenchmark(f(x), g(x))
# Unit: nanoseconds
#  expr  min     lq median     uq   max neval
#  f(x) 2320 2642.5 2757.5 2864.0 24662   100
#  g(x)  955 1080.0 1408.0 1487.5 12219   100
```

Comment: `(x > 0) + 0` as well. Fun and games abound.

Comment: If the nanoseconds matter, you might be able to squeeze a little bit more speed out of a less "trickery"-based approach like `as.numeric(as.logical(x))`.